# django social auth error after completing pipeline

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using django social auth to power facebook connect in my app (admittedly with a little complicated user model and legacy database).

I was redirected to error page and seem to be running into an error AFTER completion of pipeline( redirect as last step of pipeline still redirects me).

Can someone tell me where to look to debug this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post detailed error messages ?

Comment: it just redirects me to the error page. Hence I need to understand where should I look to debug.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be to look in social-auth's [views.py](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/views.py), at the few places where the redirect to LOGIN_ERROR_URL happens (the variable url is set to LOGIN_ERROR_URL and then HttpResponseRedirect(url) is called). Add some print statements, or better, set breakpoints using [the python debugger](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). If you run your app in the Django development server, the print statements will show up in the terminal in which you ran the server. Otherwise, they may show up in your server logs, depending on your configuration. You may also find [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) helpful.

Using print statements or the debugger, my workflow would be:

1. Figure out what line in views.py the redirect is triggered from
2. Figure out what condition causes that line to be reached
3. Inspect the variables leading to that condition

Sorry this is so general. Happy to help more if you can provide some more specific information.

Aaron